# Launcher icon gets chosen from different drawable density folder

Tags: android

So I am having a weird problem. I was redecorating my app for devices that fall under the screen density of extra extra extra high dots per inch (xxx-hdpi). I created a new folder namely `drawable-xxxhdpi` and put my launcher icon `ic_launcher.png`with the size of 192 x 192 px. But, when I compiled the app and ran it in my Nexus 5, the app would pick icon resource from `drawable-xxhdpi` folder. (I know that because all the other app icons are bigger and I checked their compiled .apk file to confirm their presence in the respective `drawable` folders.

It gets weirder: when I removed the launcher icon from `drawable-xxhdpi` and put the `drawable-xxxhdpi` icon in former folder, Android WOULD pick that icon up and show it as the launcher icon.
And apparently, [I'm not the only one having this problem](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63022).

So, what to do about it?

**Edit:** On second thought, Nexus 5 ought to fall under the category of xx-hdpi devices (480dpi) but why do all the other apps have bigger icons (the ones used in xxx-hdpi)?

Comment: That's weird, maybe they put the higher res icons in a lower res folder?

Comment: Let me unzip the APK's and check it out.

Comment: @Lukos They actually don't do that. They have respective icons in their respective density folders. The plot thickens....

Comment: Hmm, maybe they hard-coded some weirdness. This case is too hot for me to handle.